# How to have path alias in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, root, resolve

Let's say i have following codes:

```
var mod1 = require('../../../../ok/mod1');
var mod2 = require('../../../info/mod2');
```

It's not pretty coding like above, i am wondering if there is a way to configure the root resolver just like [webpack-resolve-root](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root) in nodejs?

So far as i know, the `NODE_PATH` can be used to replace the root of `node_modules`, but that's not what i want. I'd like to have the resolver to resolve multiple folders in order.

Answer (score 43):

Updated answer for 2021.

[nodejs subpath imports](https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#packages_subpath_imports) have been added in: v14.6.0, v12.19.0

This allows for you to add the following to package.json

```
"imports": {
  "#ok/*": "./some-path/ok/*"
  "#info/*": "./some-other-path/info/*"
},
```

and in your .js

```
import mod1 from '#ok/mod1';
import mod2 from '#info/mod2';
```

Comment: could this work with const mod = require('')?

Comment: oh, that's a good question. Especially as it's what OP asked about.
I don't know, but I doubt it.

Comment: It actually works with const mod = require('') as well.

Comment: Is there a way to make this work for an external folder that sits beyond the node root? E.g: a server and shared folder, with server being a package that has the subpath import defined to the shared folder.

Was hoping for this to work:
`"#shared/*": "../shared/src/*"`

Comment: This works with typescript but you do need to use "#" instead of "@".

tsconfig.json: `"paths": { "#pkg2/*": ["./pkg2/*"] },`
package.json: `"imports": { "#pkg2/*": "./pkg2/*" }`

Comment: does nodejs version 16 have this? only v14.6.0, v12.19.0?

Comment: @May'Habit yes 16 has this.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work. I remember the "@" was working with me with some previous project..

Comment: OK. I found it in the tsconfig.json file.

Comment: Are any changes required for a node.js typescript project working with webpack?

Answer (score 15):

There is an npm package called [module-alias](https://www.npmjs.com/package/module-alias) that may do what you are looking for.

Comment: Is it possible to retain path intellisense with this package? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53693686)

Comment: Beware that package has some issues. It wipes your entire repository. Apparently it happens for few users. There is no solution for the data loss. Make sure you commit all your changes before you use this module

Comment: package.json "imports" is the way to go.  See newer answers.

Answer (score -6):

The best way to approach this would be to use a global (config) container.
In most cases you will have a config file in your application. In this config you can add a property which will be an object containing all absolute paths to files/folders. 
Because config files are used at the start of you application, you just do the following:

```
var config = require("./config.js");
//config = {... , path: {"someModule": "/absolute/path/to", "someModule2": "/absolute/path/to"...}}
global.CONFIG_CONTAINER = config
```

Later on in your application you can just use

```
var myModule = require(CONFIG_CONTAINER.path.someModule)
// + concat if you are looking for a file
```

In case you have some complex paths and you need a more dynamic system, you can always implement a function inside the config that will build paths for you. ( config.makePath = function(){...} )
That should take care of it in a nutshell.

Comment: I cannot using this way. I am front-end developer, and i am using `webpack` as devtool to compile the source code written in commonjs.
Once i'd like to write unit-test, i found the module cannot be loaded correctly, since the paths i am using in `require` are resolved by the [webpack-resolve-root](http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-root)