# eslint and using the NODE_PATH env var for importing modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, lint, eslint

I'm getting errors on local modules.

Using the following to start my application:

`"start": "NODE_PATH=\"$(pwd)\" node -r babel-register -r babel-polyfill src/index.js",`

By setting `NODE_PATH` to the root directory where `package.json` lies enables me to write imports from the root:

`import config from 'src/utils/config';`

This is annoying the `import/no-extraneous-dependencies` rule. If I write the relative path it doesn't complain. Is there a way for `eslint` to recognize the root directory as the starting path for module import paths?

Comment: This might help: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import#resolvers

Answer (score -2):

Doing things differently probably rightfully makes some linting rules break. Or else let's bug-report the lint rule.

You avoid the initial `./` in every import but is there some other reasons for doing things this way?

There might be other ways to achieve your goal(s).
Npm aliases or subpath imports perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67825148/296639