# How to import from a constructed string path?

Tags: javascript

How is possible to import like below in javascript:

`import default_import from "path_string_1"+"path_string_2";`

In my case, I am interested to import near to project root from a deep inside module:

`import class_name from process.cwd()+"/folder_name/module_name.js";`

Comment: Do you have to do this? If so, you have to use dynamic imports.

Comment: It is not a must, but I am tired of typing `../` multiple times

Comment: You might wanna look into setting up a path alias

Comment: Answer: [You can see this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33214780/how-to-have-path-alias-in-nodejs).

Comment: I am not able to make it work. :-/